# R subsetting data frame by column

Tags: r

For an assignment, I have written a function with "id" as an argument, in which I create a null data frame, then in a for loop read the number of complete cases (no NAs) in a series of CSV files. This gives me a data frame "dat" with two columns (id, # complete cases), which I have verified. Now I'm having trouble subsetting this based on the id argument. I should be able to subset by column 1 which is equivalent to the id:

```
dat[which(dat[, 1] %in% id),]
```

but when I run this function, nothing is returned (no output, no error). After some searching on this site and others, I tried naming the columns when I created the data frame, to have something to call the column in subsetting:

```
dat <- data.frame("monitor"=integer(), "nobs"=integer())
dat_subset <- dat[which(dat[, "monitor"] %in% id),]
```

but this returns "undefined columns selected". So I tried specifying my data frame another way:

```
dat <- data.frame(ncol=2)
colnames(dat) <- c("ID", "nobs")
```

but this gives error 'names' attribute [2] must be same length as vector [1]. What is the length 1 vector? Didn't I ask for a 2 column data frame?

Can anyone help me to debug any of these options? Many thanks!

Edit based on feedback: I initialized by data frame properly (thanks to the comments). 
    dat <- data.frame("ID" = integer(0), "nobs" = integer(0))
`Str(dat)` shows I have done this correctly
    'data.frame':   0 obs. of  2 variables:
     $ ID  : int 
     $ nobs: int 
So it seems that my problem lies in the for loop that follows, as using `str(dat)` after the loop shows the column names have been dropped:

```
for (i in 1:332) {
        nobs <- sum(complete.cases(read.csv(files_list[i])))
        rowvector <- c(i,nobs)
        dat <- rbind(dat, rowvector)
  }
'data.frame':   332 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ X1L  : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ X117L: int  117 1041 243 474 402 228 442 192 275 148 ...
```

Why would the names not stick when adding lines to the data frame? `?rbind` states that "column names are taken from the first argument with appropriate names".

Comment: See `?data.frame`. There isn't `ncol` argument in the function. If you use `data.frame(ncol=2)` and print it out, you will see a `data.frame` with a column, named as `ncol`.

Comment: there are many concepts to explain here. too wide question. One mistake I can find is dat[,1] returns a data.frame and you might want to use the `drop = TRUE` argument to make it a vector

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are looking for, making use of the `subset` function.

```
fun <- function(want) {
  # Here's a random example
  # dat <- data.frame(id = rep(1:3, each = 3),
  #                   n_complete = as.integer(runif(9, max = 100)))
  # > str(dat)
  # 'data.frame':   9 obs. of  2 variables:
  #   $ id        : int  1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3
  #   $ n_complete: int  3 80 5 84 67 83 48 49 52

  # Or using the file reading code from the question edit
  # dat <- data.frame(id = integer(), n_complete = integer())
  # for (i in 1:332) {
  #   nobs <- sum(complete.cases(read.csv(files_list[i])))
  #   dat <- rbind(dat, data.frame(id = i, n_complete = nobs))
  # }

  # Better yet, preallocate dat before filling
  dat <- data.frame(id = 1:332, n_complete = 0)
  for (i in dat$id) {
    nobs <- sum(complete.cases(read.csv(files_list[i])))
    dat$n_complete[i] <- nobs
  }

  # Subset by requesting specific id values
  return(subset(dat, id %in% want))
}

# Ask for ids 1 and 2
fun(c(1, 2))
# > str(fun(c(1, 2)))
# 'data.frame': 6 obs. of  2 variables:
#   $ id        : int  1 1 1 2 2 2
#   $ n_complete: int  3 80 5 84 67 83
```

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Yes, useful to use str to see where I stand. I've now initialized my data frame with column names correctly: dat <- data.frame("ID" = integer(0), "nobs" = integer(0)) and str(dat) shows me 'data.frame': 0 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ ID  : int 
 $ nobs: int

Comment: sorry for the half-comment, just figuring out this system!

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your question, but I think all you need to do is add your code that reads in the data where I created a sample of `dat` and this is capable of subsetting it. If you have more issues, read in your data and paste the output of `str(dat)`

Comment: thanks Ben, I added further info in the original question

Comment: `rbind()` doesn't know how to combine a data.frame and a vector. Instead of using rowvector, create a new data.frame like this and see if you get better results. This would be more efficient if you preallocate your dat data.frame before filling it but this will work with the example you gave.

Comment: Aha! Setting `n_complete = 0` then assigning my `nobs` directly to `dat$nobs[i]` did the trick. Thank you!

Comment: If this is helpful, please mark this as the answer so that others may find it more easily.